# Javascript equivalent regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

Whats the javascript equivalent of

```
$tring="I love my #newJob";

preg_replace('/(#)(\w+)/i', '<a href="index.php?mod=tags&id=\2">\1\2</a>', $tring);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost same except: backreferences are `$n` form instead of `\n`, using regular expression literal instead of string.

```js
string = "I love my #newJob";
string.replace(/(#)(\w+)/i, '<a href="index.php?mod=tags&id=$2">$1$2</a>')
// => "I love my <a href="index.php?mod=tags&id=newJob">#newJob</a>"
```